# regarding some questions on upanayana

Tags: practice, vedic-rituals, yagnopavitam

In the uponayana ceremony, the boys should take 3 steps. Why the boys are stopped at 2.5 steps to remains at home? Is that mean we are not following the actual procedure?

Comment: You should ask question with proper title. Else, you question will be ambiguous and you may even get downvotes.

Comment: Upanayana conduct mostly when boy entered age at 8 (consider as age 7), I think 3rd step indicated "Debt to the God" because of that parents didn't want/allow boys to do that at young age (If you asking about 3 standards, if not please rephrase your question and add better title)

Comment: Please do the required edit. My English is bad and I was unable to pose the question in a right way. What I was asking is, if the right procedure is to take 3 steps and we are stopped at 2 and half steps then we don't follow the procedure. Hence the Uponayana is not valid. Is it true?

Comment: Upanayana means the initiation of studies in the gurukulam after getting the gayAtri mantra upadesham. The child after the ceremony proceeds straight to the gurukulam for the studies of shastra. This was the practice followed in the ancient days. However, in today's time most of us do not go to Gurukula. Hence the maternal uncle usually stops the child once he commences his journey towards the gurukula. This has become a custom that the child should be stopped else he will proceed to the gurukula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upanayana means the initiation of studies in the gurukulam after getting the gayAtri mantra upadesham.

The child after the ceremony proceeds straight to the gurukulam for the studies of shastra.

> Traditionally these boys were sent to ashrams with the gurus to learn
>   in a gurukul system of education but in modern times this act of the
>   boy doing for first alms round in town and leaving his family for
>   gurus hermitage is done symbolically within the family and is later
>   stopped by his maternal uncle (Mama) from leaving. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upanayana#cite_note-Shore-33)

This was the practice followed in the ancient days. However, in today's time most of us do not go to Gurukula. Hence the maternal uncle usually stops the child once he commences his journey towards the gurukula.

This has become a custom that the child should be stopped else he will proceed to the gurukula.

Comment: Answers on this site should be backed up with details and sources (preferably scripture), so I'm deleting your answer and converting it to a comment.  If you want to expand this into a proper answer, then edit it and flag me to undelete it.

Comment: OK, I'm undeleting your answer.